# How to extract unique value from a string in excel and

Tags: excel

So this is what i have:

```
Column A                 Column B

Junior,Jeff,Raul,Sam     Junior,Raul,Sam
```

I would like to create a Column C with the unique value in a string based on the comparison from A and B.  In this case, output will be

```
Column A                 Column B               Column C

Junior,Jeff,Raul,Sam     Junior,Raul,Sam        jeff
```

Comment: You will have to show what you have attempted.

Comment: I have no idea on how to do that, and i have been looking for VBA formulas still havent found or come out with any solution.

Comment: OK. I have posted a solution below. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UDF needs to be prepared by inserting a module in Visual Basic Editor and pasting below code.

```
Public Function CompareCell(strCellFirst As String, strCellScnd As String, Optional strDelim)
Dim arrFirst, arrScnd
Dim i As Long
Dim objCol As New Collection
Dim strOut As String
If IsMissing(strDelim) Then
    strDelim = ","
End If
arrFirst = Split(strCellFirst, strDelim)
arrScnd = Split(strCellScnd, strDelim)
For i = LBound(arrFirst) To UBound(arrFirst)
    If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(arrFirst(i), arrScnd, 0)) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        objCol.Add arrFirst(i), arrFirst(i)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next i
For i = LBound(arrScnd) To UBound(arrScnd)
    If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(arrScnd(i), arrFirst, 0)) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        objCol.Add arrScnd(i), arrScnd(i)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To objCol.Count
    strOut = strOut & " " & objCol(i)
Next i
CompareCell = Replace(Trim(strOut), " ", strDelim)
End Function
```

To use it then you can use it in Excel sheet as:

```
=CompareCell(A2,B2)
```

Note: If delimiter is not specified then comma will be considered as default. Suppose you want to some other character such as semicolon as delimiter then formula will look like

```
=CompareCell(A2,B2,";")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does exactly what i was looking for.